# Exclude a variable from glm()

Tags: r, model, glm

I have multiple datasets where the response variable is always in the last column of the data frame. I want to run a GLM (logistic regression) and automate it. I call `glm()` by position but this method always includes the last variable.

```
data(iris)
head(iris) 
train<- iris 
logit <- glm(train[,length(train)]~ . , 
             data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(logit)
```

I tried writting `train[,length(train)]~ . -train[,length(train)]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Using position is a bad design since it can lead to many unexpected problems. Use names instead.

Comment: @Sonny yes but i have 100 dataset with differents name but always y var is in the last position.

Comment: by last position you mean it's the final column in the data.frame?

Comment: try this: 

logit <- glm(train[[ncol(train)]] ~  . , data = train[,-ncol(train)], family = "binomial")

Comment: @AndryasWaurzenczak, could OP also just keep the .? I was going to recommend .[,-ncol(.)], but Rstudio is taking too long to open so I can't test it.

Comment: @Andrew Yes! i'm going to update it.

Comment: In this case,  the best thing you can do is to rename the last column to a generic name, for exame Y, and use this to fit the model.

Comment: colnames(train)[ncol(train)] <- "Y"
model <- glm(Y ~ ., data = train, family = "binomial")

Comment: @AndryasWaurzenczak it works logit <- glm(train[[ncol(train)]] ~ . , data = train[,-ncol(train)], family = "binomial") .

Answer (score 1):

Quite verbose but I think that should work :

```
logit <- glm(formula(paste0(names(train)[length(train)], '~.')), 
             data = train, 
             family = "binomial")
```

or using `tail` :

```
logit <- glm(formula(paste0(tail(names(train), 1), '~.')), 
             data = train, 
             family = "binomial")
```

Comment: or `glm(reformulate(".",response=tail(names(train),1)), ...)`